# Update Line Chart (High Charts) after applying filter

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a combine chart with dual Y axis . I have a submit button which when clicked should update the line series chart . The current data present in the line series chart is `[42.857142857142854,36.36363636363637,50,100,37.5,66.66666666666666,66.66666666666666,50,50,21.428571428571427,23.076923076923077,33.33333333333333,75,100,100,50,100,50]`

when I click on the Submit Button at the very bottom it should update this data so the line series chart(Orange one on JSFiddle) gets updated with new values . I did the update using the below code but the line chart does not get updated properly

```
function update(){
var seriesChart = chart.series[0];
seriesChart.update({
data:percentageDataUpdate}); 
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how I can solve this .

JSFiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/q6ybvpgt/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`Series.setData`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData) api for Series chart, setting the `updatePoints` option to `false` should do the job:

```js
function update() {
  chart.series[0].setData(percentageDataUpdate, true, true, false);
}
```

Under [`Series.update`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update):

> Note that Series.update may mutate the passed data options.

And the [error](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/15) that you're getting:

> ## Highcharts expects data to be sorted
>
> This happens when creating a line series or a stock chart where the data is not sorted in ascending X
>   order.
>
> For performance reasons, Highcharts does not sort the data, instead it
>   requires that the implementer pre-sorts the data.

```js
var percentageDataUpdate = [7.142857142857142, 9.090909090909092, 0, 0, 12.5, 33.33333333333333, 33.33333333333333, 50, 0, 7.142857142857142, 7.6923076923076925, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0];

var barData = [{ "name": "A", "y": 56 }, { "name": "B", "y": 44 }, { "name": "C", "y": 8 }, { "name": "D", "y": 8 }, { "name": "E", "y": 32 }, { "name": "F", "y": 12 }, { "name": "G", "y": 12 }, { "name": "H", "y": 8 }, { "name": "I", "y": 8 }, { "name": "J", "y": 56 }, { "name": "K", "y": 52 }, { "name": "L", "y": 12 }, { "name": "M", "y": 16 }, { "name": "N", "y": 8 }, { "name": "O", "y": 8 }, { "name": "P", "y": 8 }, { "name": "Q", "y": 8 }, { "name": "R", "y": 8 } ]


var yAxis = [

  { // Secondary yAxis
    title: {
      text: 'Error Percentage',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value}',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    max: 100,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    opposite: true

  },
  { // Primary yAxis

    title: {
      text: ' Average Count',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value} ',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    }
  }
];



var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Error Distribution (Days)'
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Value Type'
    },

    type: 'category',
    crosshair: true
  },

  yAxis: yAxis,




  series: [{
      name: 'Percentage',
      type: 'line',
      data: [42.857142857142854, 36.36363636363637, 50, 100, 37.5, 66.66666666666666, 66.66666666666666, 50, 50, 21.428571428571427, 23.076923076923077, 33.33333333333333, 75, 100, 100, 50, 100, 50],
      color: "#FFA500"
    },
    {
      name: "Count Distribution by Types",
      type: 'column',
      yAxis: 1,
      data: barData,
      color: "#7cb5ec"
    },
  ]
});

function update() {
  chart.series[0].setData(percentageDataUpdate, true, true, false);
}
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
  height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
  background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <input type="button" onClick="update()" value="Submit" />
</figure>
```

A hack: if you really need to use update, do it twice:

```js
function update() {
  chart.series[0].update({ data: [] });
  chart.series[0].update({ data: percentageDataUpdate });
}
```

```js
var percentageDataUpdate = [7.142857142857142, 9.090909090909092, 0, 0, 12.5, 33.33333333333333, 33.33333333333333, 50, 0, 7.142857142857142, 7.6923076923076925, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0];

var barData = [{ "name": "A", "y": 56 }, { "name": "B", "y": 44 }, { "name": "C", "y": 8 }, { "name": "D", "y": 8 }, { "name": "E", "y": 32 }, { "name": "F", "y": 12 }, { "name": "G", "y": 12 }, { "name": "H", "y": 8 }, { "name": "I", "y": 8 }, { "name": "J", "y": 56 }, { "name": "K", "y": 52 }, { "name": "L", "y": 12 }, { "name": "M", "y": 16 }, { "name": "N", "y": 8 }, { "name": "O", "y": 8 }, { "name": "P", "y": 8 }, { "name": "Q", "y": 8 }, { "name": "R", "y": 8 } ]


var yAxis = [

  { // Secondary yAxis
    title: {
      text: 'Error Percentage',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value}',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    max: 100,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    opposite: true

  },
  { // Primary yAxis

    title: {
      text: ' Average Count',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value} ',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    }
  }
];



var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Error Distribution (Days)'
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Value Type'
    },

    type: 'category',
    crosshair: true
  },

  yAxis: yAxis,




  series: [{
      name: 'Percentage',
      type: 'line',
      data: [42.857142857142854, 36.36363636363637, 50, 100, 37.5, 66.66666666666666, 66.66666666666666, 50, 50, 21.428571428571427, 23.076923076923077, 33.33333333333333, 75, 100, 100, 50, 100, 50],
      color: "#FFA500"
    },
    {
      name: "Count Distribution by Types",
      type: 'column',
      yAxis: 1,
      data: barData,
      color: "#7cb5ec"
    },
  ]
});

function update() {
  chart.series[0].update({ data: [] });
  chart.series[0].update({ data: percentageDataUpdate });
}
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
  height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
  background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <input type="button" onClick="update()" value="Submit" />
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which I can suggest is to define the x values for the updated data, that's also will sort the data.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6zdkxby4/

```
 var percentageDataUpdate = [{
   x: 0,
   y: 7.142857142857142
 }, {
   x: 1,
   y: 9.090909090909092
 }, {
   x: 2,
   y: 0
 }, {
   x: 3,
   y: 0
 }, {
   x: 4,
   y: 12.5
 }...
 }];
```